# MPU-6050 Burst Read Auto Increment

Tags: i2c, mpu6050

I'm trying to write a driver for the MPU-6050 and I'm stuck on how to proceed regarding reading the raw accelerometer/gyroscope/temperature readings. For instance, the MPU-6050 has the accelerometer X readings in 2 registers: ACCEL_XOUT[15:8] at address 0x3B and ACCEL_XOUT[7:0] at address 0x3C. Of course to read the raw value I need to read both registers and put them together.

**BUT**

In the description of the registers (in the register map and description sheet, https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf) it says that to guarantee readings from the same sampling instant I must use burst reads b/c as soon as an idle I2C bus is detected, the sensor registers are refreshed with new data from a new sampling instant. The datasheet snippet shows the simple I2C burst read:

[image]

However, this approach (to the best of my understanding) would only work reading the ACCEL_X registers from the same sampling instant if the auto-increment was supported (such that the first DATA in the above sequence would be from ACCEL_XOUT[15:8] @ address 0x3B and the second DATA would be from ACCEL_XOUT[7:0] @ address 0x3C). But the datasheet (https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) only mentions that I2C burst writes support the auto-increment feature. Without auto-increment on the I2C read side how would I go about reading two different registers whilst maintaining the same sampling instant?

I also recognize that I could use the sensor's FIFO feature or the interrupt to accomplish what I'm after, but (for my own curiosity) I would like a solution that didn't rely on either.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, looks like the documentation on this topic is incomplete.

### Reading single sample

I think you can burst read the `ACCEL_*OUT_*`, `TEMP_OUT_*` and `GYRO_*OUT_*`. In fact I tried reading the data one register at once, but I got frequent data corruption.
Then, just to try, I requested 6 bytes from `ACCEL_XOUT_H`, 6 bytes from `GYRO_XOUT_H` and 2 bytes from `TEMP_OUT_H` and... it worked! No more data corruption!

I think they simply forgot to mention this in the register map.

#### How to

Here is some example code that can work in the Arduino environment.

These are the function that I use, they are not very safe, but it works for my project:

```cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
inline void requestBytes(byte SUB, byte nVals)
{
    Wire.beginTransmission(SAD);
    Wire.write(SUB);
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.requestFrom(SAD, nVals);
    while (Wire.available() == 0);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
inline byte getByte(void)
{
    return Wire.read();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
inline void stopRead(void)
{
    Wire.endTransmission(true);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
byte readByte(byte SUB)
{
    requestBytes(SUB, 1);

    byte result = getByte();

    stopRead();

    return result;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void readBytes(byte SUB, byte* buff, byte count)
{
    requestBytes(SUB, count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        buff[i] = getByte();

    stopRead();
}
```

At this point, you can simply read the values in this way:

```cpp
// ACCEL_XOUT_H

// burst read the registers using auto-increment:
byte data[6];
readBytes(ACCEL_XOUT_H, data, 6);

// convert the data:
acc_x = (data[0] << 8) | data[1];
// ...
```

#### Warning!

Looks like this cannot be done for other registers. For example, to read the FIFO_COUNT_* I have to do this (otherwise I get incorrect results):

```cpp
uint16_t FIFO_size(void)
{
    byte bytes[2];

    // this does not work
    //readBytes(FIFO_COUNT_H, bytes, 2);

    bytes[1] = readByte(FIFO_COUNT_H);
    bytes[2] = readByte(FIFO_COUNT_L);

    return unisci_bytes(bytes[1], bytes[2]);
}
```

### Reading the FIFO

Looks like the FIFO works differently: you can burst read by simply requesting multiple bytes from the `FIFO_R_W` register and the MPU6050 will give you the bytes in the FIFO without incrementing the register.

I found [this](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/e75c80db2c212f57284255bcc693ab82cf7f1219/Arduino/MPU6050/MPU6050.cpp#L2732) example where they use `I2Cdev::readByte(SAD, FIFO_R_W, buffer)` to read a given number of bytes from the FIFO and if you look at `I2Cdev::readByte()` ([here](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/e75c80db2c212f57284255bcc693ab82cf7f1219/Arduino/I2Cdev/I2Cdev.cpp#L211)) it simply requests N bytes from the FIFO register:

```cpp
// ... send FIFO_R_W and request N bytes ...

for(...; ...; count++)
    data[count] = Wire.receive();
// ...
```

#### How to

This is simple since the FIFO_R_W does not auto-increment:

```cpp
byte data[12];

void loop() {
// ...
readBytes(FIFO_R_W, data, 12); // <- replace 12 with your burst size
// ...
}
```

#### Warning!

- Using `FIFO_size()` is very slow!
- Also my advice is to use 400kHz I2C frequency, which is the MPU6050's maximum speed

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Luca says, the burst read semantic seems to be different depending on the register the read operation starts at.

### Reading consistent samples

To read a consistent set of raw data values, you can use the method `I2C.readRegister(int, ByteBuffer, int)` with register number 59 (ACCEL_XOUTR[15:8]) and a length of 14 to read all the sensor data ACCEL, TEMP, and GYRO in one operation and get consistent data.

### Burst read of FIFO data

However, if you use the FIFO buffer of the chip, you can start the burst read with the same method signature on register 116 (FIFO_R_W) to read the given amount of data from the chip-internal fifo buffer. Doing so you must keep in mind that there is a limit on the number of bytes that can be read in one burst operation. If I'm interpreting https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/c33738a320a3e28824af7807edafda440952c05d/pigpio.c#L3914 right, a maximum of 31 bytes can be read in a single burst operation.